# Is JDBC 4 fully compliant with JDBC 3?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, websphere

Programmer A, wrote an application using JDBC 3 (db2jcc.jar) and deployed on WebSphere App Server.

Is it ok to change JDBC connection to use JDBC 4 (db2jcc4.jar), instead of JDBC 3 ?

Is JDBC 4 fully compliant with JDBC 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JDBC 4 shall be backward compatible with JDBC 3 and you shall have no problems replacing the driver.

Quoting from [JDBC 4.0 specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr221/index.html) 2.2 Overview of goal section, one of the goals of JDBC 4.0 is to

> 8) Maintain backward compatibility with existing applications and drivers Existing JDBC technology-enabled drivers ( JDBC drivers) and
>   the applications that use them must continue to work in an
>   implementation of the Java virtual machine that supports the JDBC 4.0
>   API. Applications that use only features defined in earlier releases
>   of the JDBC API will not require changes to continue running. It
>   should be straightforward for existing applications to migrate to JDBC
>   4.0 technology.